# What is the number of observations required for adequate Krippendorff's alpha?

Tags: agreement-statistics, corpus-linguistics

say I am working on a project to classify a number of documents. Say I have 2,000 newspaper articles that I would like to code as either containing information of lawnmowers (1) or not (0). This is a binary classification. Now I have two coders that will perform the classification.

My initial idea is to have both of them perform the classification on 1,000 articles each. But I need a test for intercoder reliability. The test I am planning on performing is the Krippendorff's Alpha. That means I will have to require both coders to perform the classification on the same set of articles, or at least on a fraction of overlapping articles.

My question is: what would be the best setup for the Krippendorff's Alpha test? How many overlapping articles should both coders perform the classification on? I have not yet found any info on how overlap there should be..

Background info: the 2,000 articles are a sample of a larger corpus (approx. 250,000 articles) themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Select the articles at random so that the sample is not biased by ordering. If you have some important subgroupings, consider stratified random sampling. Including more articles will yield a more precise estimate of the coders' inter-rater reliability (e.g., a smaller standard error or a narrower confidence interval). Note that adding more articles will not increase the estimate itself, just your confidence that it is a trustworthy estimate. I would also caution against testing if alpha is significantly different from zero. This practice is not very meaningful - it is better to just report the estimate and a measure of its precision, then interpret whether the estimated reliability is adequate for the purpose you want to use the codes for.

I would guess that you could get a suitably precise estimate with 100-300 articles. It really depends on a cost-benefit analysis (e.g., how hard is it to double code each additional article and how much precision do you need?).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helps :)